# document.selection.createRange() not working in chrome and safari

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a textbox with textmode as multiline option its working fine in IE,Mozilla problem occurs in Chrome and safari. Sample code folows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRootDescription" onpaste="DoPaste(this);" Width="600px" Rows="10" Columns="72" MaxLength="500" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

function DoPaste(control) {
maxLength = control.attributes["maxlength"].value;   
if (maxLength) {        
    var oTR = control.document.selection.createRange();     
}}
```

in chrome it gives me an error as "Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined"

Answer (score 7):

In **non IE (excluding IE9)** browsers (see comments), use `window.getSelection` to get the selection object. In IE < 9, original code should work.

```
function GetSelection () {
    if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
        var selectionRange = window.getSelection ();                                        
        return selectionRange.toString();
    } 
    else {
        if (document.selection.type == 'None') {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
            return textRange.text;
        }
    }
}

function DoPaste(control) {
    maxLength = control.attributes["maxlength"].value;   
    if (maxLength) {        
        var oTR = GetSelection();     
    }
}
```

In general, working with `selection` and `ranges` is very tricky as browser supports varies so much.

Here's an excellent reference which lists out browser support (and what code works where) and sample code that works in corresponding browsers: http://help.dottoro.com/ljefwsqm.php

Comment: In IE, your original code will work. If you check the reference, it tells you what code is supported in what browser. I find it very helpful and they have sample cross broswer code too.

Comment: Opera 10.5 supports `window.getSelection()` too. What distinction is there between Opera pre and post 10.5?

Comment: @Tim Down: Are you sure? Usually dottoro is right about the browser support thing. But anyway, I would check for `if(window.getSelection)` and not any specific browser version so if its there, the code would work.

Comment: @Mrchief: Yes, I'm sure. What I think has confused things is that according to dottoro, they removed `document.selection` in 10.5, but it definitely had `window.getSelection()` before that (I'm certain some version 9.x had it), so there was overlap. See http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvonpc.php

Comment: @Tim Down: I See. I edited my answer to reflect the same. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of foibles when getting selected text in a document, mostly related to whether or not text is selected in a form control or as text of some other element. Try a function that does something like:

```
function checkForSelectedText(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var tagName = el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var t;
  var d = document;

  // Try DOM 2 Range - for most browsers, including IE 6+
  // However, doesn't get text selected inside form controls
  // that allow selection of text content (input type text, 
  // textarea)
  if (d && d.selection && d.selection.createRange) {
    t = d.selection.createRange().text;

  // Otherwise try HTML5 - note that getSelection returns
  // a string with extra properties. This may also get
  // text within input and textarea
  } else if (d.getSelection) {
    t = d.getSelection();
  }

  // If didn't get any text, see if event was inside
  // inupt@type=text or textarea and look for text
  if (t == '') {
    if (tagName == 'textarea' || 
       (tagName == 'input' && el.type == 'text')) {

     // Check selectionStart/End as otherwise if no text
     // selected, IE returns entire text of element
     if (typeof el.selectionStart == 'number' && 
         el.selectionStart != el.selectionEnd) {
        t = el.value.substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd)
     }
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery to do the same because it's cross browser and you write more abstract java script instead of the native browser specific one your wrote so far.

Comment: What method in jQuery does that? This should be a comment anyway (unless improved upon).

Comment: Best jquery function for selecting text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse/987376#987376

Comment: @drharris - that function uses browser sniffing so if you turn up with a browser other than the 4 sniffed for, bad luck.

Comment: The answer below it mods it to use null checks instead of browser sniffing.

Comment: Selecting text is always not the same as working with ranges.