# document.selection.createRange().text convert to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is meaning of following code, I want to convert in to jquery for browser compatibility.

```
document.selection.createRange().text
```

Comment: Nor sure if it does everything you need, but take a look here: http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.selection.createRange() not working in chrome and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021497/document-selection-createrange-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari)

Answer (score 1):

`document.selection` is an IE-specific legacy way to get text that the user has "selected" (highlighted with the mouse) on a web page.

It's now deprecated in favour of the standards-based `document.getSelection()` - see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) for more info.

There are already jQuery plugins that make this cross-browser, e.g [jquery-textrange](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange)